# Run leafpad with CRON at reboot

Tags: x11, cron, reboot

Why any of my crontab lines do not work? I have been restarting my Debian few times and no leafpad window has appeared. Debian Jessie with LXDE.

crontab run as root:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot /usr/bin/leafpad
@reboot echo '/usr/bin/leafpad' | at now + 1 minutes
@reboot echo "sleep 10;/usr/bin/leafpad" | at now
```

**edit**
My question is to learn CRON. Not init.d.

**edit**
I need it to be run as root. I actually don't need to run leafpad but get to know why CRON cannot do that. What is the problem for CRON. This is my CRON learning.

Comment: @Gilles I need to learn CRON. Because I must get to know if CRON is able to run an application of graphical environment as root when  graphical environment is ran by normal user.

Comment: Neither cron nor init.d can do this.

Comment: And CRON cannot open leafpad?

Comment: No, you need to log in first. See the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: I think you put your `leafpad.desktop` file into `~/.config/autostart/` this way it should be started when you log-in. however for a cron-job you'd need to add `export DISPLAY=:0.0` to your cron line, because the env is not set.

Comment: @Michael D. But in this way leafpad will not be run by root. I need it to be run as root. I actually don't need to run leafpad but get to know why CRON cannot do that. What is the problemfor CRON. This is my CRON learning.

Comment: People who set up and maintain software environments use `cron` to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals. It typically automates system maintenance or administration—though its general-purpose nature makes it useful for things like downloading files from the Internet and downloading email at regular intervals.

Comment: Ok but I would like to see what are cron problems with running user's gui applications. I know this normal usagae of CRON. The question is not ''for what is CRON